# Unexpected Output File Upload PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have the following code, but even when I upload a valid image it echoes "Error: your file cannot be uploaded". It's passing all the checks but something is going wrong with the saving to a folder. I have a directory called 'uploads' in the same directory as the php file, so I'm not sure why it isn't saving the images there. I know I could do it with a database but I'm not too sure how. I just want to be able to save the uploaded images somewhere, and display the most recently uploaded image on the page.

Any tips on how to get this to work would be thoroughly appreciated.
Thanks!

upload.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>File Upload</h1>
        </header>
        <form action="/fileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <br>
            Select image to upload: 
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

fileUpload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadCheck = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadCheck = 1;
    } else {
        echo "Error: the file you attempted to upload is not an image";
        $uploadCheck = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Error: file already exists.";
    $uploadCheck = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Error: file is too large.";
    $uploadCheck = 0;
}

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Error: incompatible type. only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files.";
    $uploadCheck = 0;
}

if ($uploadCheck == 0) {
    echo "Error: your file was not uploaded.";

} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Success! Your file - ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " - has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Error: your file could not be uploaded";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is here ( it contained errors),

1. First of all in Upload.html change /fileUpload.php to fileupload.php.
2. In upload.html & fileUpload.php, name attribute for file should be same.

upload.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
         <title>File Upload</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <header>
             <h1>File Upload</h1>
         </header>
         <form action="fileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <br>
             Select image to upload: 
             <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload">

             <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
         </form>    
     </body>
     </html>
```

fileUpload.php

```
 <?php
 $target_dir = "uploads/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]);
 $uploadCheck = 1;
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
     if($check !== false) {
         $uploadCheck = 1;
     } else {
         echo "Error: the file you attempted to upload is not an image";
         $uploadCheck = 0;
     }
 }

 if (file_exists($target_file)) {
     echo "Error: file already exists.";
     $uploadCheck = 0;
 }

 if ($_FILES["fileUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
     echo "Error: file is too large.";
     $uploadCheck = 0;
 }

 if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
 && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
     echo "Error: incompatible type. only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files.";
     $uploadCheck = 0;
 }

 if ($uploadCheck == 0) {
     echo "Error: your file was not uploaded.";

 } else {
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
         echo "Success! Your file - ". basename( $_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]). " - has been uploaded.";
     } else {
         echo "Error: your file could not be uploaded";
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: All directories in the path used have read & write permissions set for all

Comment: Hey sorry, I accidentally uploaded a slightly older version to this question. I actually do use "fileUpload.php", not "/fileUpload.php". But it was that little typo in the php file, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Try using this:

```
list($name,$ext)=explode(".",$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]);
```

and then try to validate the extension part:

```
if($ext!= "jpg" && $ext!= "png" && $ext!= "jpeg"&& $ext!= "gif" )
```

I suggest you to use in_array() for the above validation like this:

```
$img_ext=array("jpg","png","jpeg","gif");
if(!in_array($ext,$img_ext)){ //Your code here }
```

Comment: everything to do with the filetype and its validation works, its purely the uploading the file to the directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$target_dir = "./uploads/";`

also if your using windows pc under a wamp Environment grant the folder permission